# Tableau Frequency Distribution - multiple groups

Tags: tableau-api

I have data which includes 2 columns, ages, and groups similar to
B 1 B 1 B 1 B 4 B 5 B 8 D 2 D 2 D 3 D 3 D 3 D 4 D 6 D 7 D 9 D 9

In Tableau, I wish to plot a line for each group B and D, % number of records(observations) (of group in group), against the age range, 1 to 9.

So B 1 - 3/6*100, B 5 1/6*100, D 3 - 3/10*100.

Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.
Enda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag 'Age' measure in columns. 
Drag 'Group' dimension in 'Color'

Drag the tableau default measure of 'Number of Records' in rows. Make it's aggregation as 'sum', add quick table calculation of 'Percent of Total'. Change it's 'Compute Using' to 'Age'.

That's it! Hopefully this is what you were trying to do.
[image: Here is a screen shot of what i did.]

Comment: Fantastic & Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! In case you are wondering how i got the (3/6) in the tooltip. I added this in the tooltip :"(<SUM(Number of Records)>/<Count of samples per grp grp>)" , Here 'Count of samples per grp grp' is a calculated field : {FIXED [Group]: COUNT([Age])} which will give you '6' for group 'B'.  You might want to mark the answer as 'correct' too so that people don't keep on answering it. cheers!